# retain the existing selection and allow user to add more selection in struts2 select tag

Tags: jsp, struts2

How can I retain the existing selection from the list when the user makes further selection in struts tag `select`.

**JSP:**

```
<s:select key="chosenId" id="chosenId" name="entity.IdList" listKey="iD" list="idList" listValue="idName" size="5" multiple="true"/>
```

For example: existing selection is `"Finance"` and test for certain object ( refer to image). When user edit that the particular object, he might want to select another `id` name.

**The problem is when user tries to select in the select box, the current selection disappears. So I want to retain the existing selection and allow the user to select more.**

What kind of approach should I make to get this kind of feature?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The approach is essential, you need the place where you can add more elements from the list. It could be `textfield`, `textarea` whatever you want. Then kindly add the event handler to the list element, when you select the items from the list simply add the current selection to the placeholder.